# Saving the input in the table using JS

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want my table to actually "save" the input (the input dialog box should disappear and the new value should take place of the old value - of course until the next reload).
Now it stays in the dialog box after the click out.

How to fix it?

```js
function edit_description() {
  var targetDescription = $("#description-1");
  var value = targetDescription.text();

  if (value != "") {
    value = ""
  };

  targetDescription.html(`<input class="description form-control" data-target="description-1" type="text" value=${value}>`);

  $("input:text").focus();

  $("input").blur(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = targetDescription.attr("data-target");
    $(`#${target}`).text($(this).val());
    var description = $(this).val();
    save_description(identification = "description-1", description);
  });
};

function save_description(identification, description) {
  console.log('Saved!');

  var userInput = {
    "identification": identification,
    "description": description
  };
};
```

```css
a[role="button"][onclick] {
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-wrapper">
  <table id="table" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><span>Edit</span></th>
        <th scope="col"><span>Description</span></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="edit-1"><a class="btn" role="button" onclick="edit_description();">Edit ></a></td>
        <td id="description-1">Lorem</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this.

Comment: Part of the problem is you're not generating new HTML correctly: by using `.html(  )` with an interpolated string without even attribute-delimiting quotes means you won't generate valid output HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get wrong variable `var target = ...`. There is a `<input>` tag in `targetDescription`, this `<input>` has attribute `data-target`. So try this.
In stead of:

```
var target = targetDescription.attr("data-target");
```

Let try:

```
var target = targetDescription.children('input').attr("data-target");
```